# After login to remote server through jump server, I can access to remote server without jump server! Why?

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, sshd

I try to tune Jump Server (very basic and simple) like [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/337274/ssh-from-a-through-b-to-c-using-private-key-on-b/337281).

Local(Me) -> Jump Server -> Remote Host

My ssh key store on Jump Server in authorized_keys and has settings like:

```
command="echo 'No access to shell, only for access to remote server'",no-pty,port-forwarding,permitopen="ip_adress:22" ssh-rsa AAAA
```

Shh key of Jump Server store in remote host

!My Local ssh key DOESN'T store in remote host authorized keys!

After this a can access to Remote Server through Jump Server via:

```
ssh -J jump_server@ip_address root@remote_ip_address
```

And it's good, but after this a can connect to the remote server without jumphost! Why?

```
ssh root@remote_ip_address
```

And I have access! Why? It's bad! I must have access to remote server only through Jump Server!

If I remove the public key of jump server from the remote server, I also cannot have access from local, but after I return the public key of Jump Server to the remote server I again have access to the remote server without Jump Server! What happened?

Comment: Are you using a `ControlMaster` setting with persistence in your `~/.ssh/config` file?

Comment: Actualy No. For the first time,  I just try to undestand simple things with ssh through authorized keys. And you now, I notice one more strange(for me) thing, even if i commented my pub_key in authorized_keys on JUMP_SERVER machine, I am anyway have access even through jump host to remote server

Comment: Did you use ProxyCommand in `~/.ssh/config` as in the guide? If you read the guide carefully, that setting makes an alias for that jump command so you can just use the remote hosts IP in your ssh command without writing in every Proxy every time you want to ssh into. If you stop sshd on the jump server, you won't be able to acces the remote(granted your remote server is only accessible through the jump server).

Comment: Yes I now about ~/.ssh/config and use it for first times, but after I decide to make "clear" variant without any configs. I just want to make things like 
ssh -J jump_server@ip_address remote_server@ip_address and have access only through this command

Comment: As you say, I stop sshd on jump server and now I don't have access via `ssh -J jump_server@ip remote_server@ip` **BUT** for now I am anyway access to remote server from my local machine! I cannot understand how if remote server dont now about MY pub key